# Count link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, onclick

I'm trying to get a method in place that registers link clicks. After reading about this subject and trying a lot I don't get it to function. My best try, which does not work, is  `<%= link_to person.name, person_url, :method => :count_new %>`. The person_url is the url I want people who click the link should go to. The count_new method looks like this:

```
stat = Stat.find_by_country(params[:country])
stat = stat.download+=1
stat.save
```

The params[:country] is in the url.
I know update_attributes works better but I'll get to that later.

I looked into counting the views on the person_url page but I really want to register clicks from different links in stead of registering views on the actual page user go to.

I'm on rails 3.

Any help is appreciated.

Rutger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stat = stat.download+=1
 ^      ^      ^
model   ^      ^ 
      model    ^
           attribute of model
```

You're trying to save an integer to your stat model when you should be updating its attribute, download (I assume).

```
@stat.update_attribute(download, :download += 1)
```

Edit

Your link_to looks off:

```
<%= link_to person.name, count_person_path, :remote => true %>
```

have this in your routes to make this work:

```
map.resources do 
  member do
    get :count
  end
end
```

also add rails 3 javascript helpers for the remote => true call:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: Mark,sorry the code I copied in was not the correct one. It was stat.download+=1 which does basically the same as your suggestion. The difficulty for me here is not so much as getting a counter going but getting it to count on a click while executing person_url.

Comment: Hard to know what your problem is but have a look at my edit, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
@stat.increment_counter('download')
```